# Fix overlapping labels in large matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, yellowbrick

I have this error in a graphing package I am using, `yellowbrick`, where, because of the extreme size of the resulting image, the labels around the graph I am trying to save do not get rendered properly.

[image]

The command I am using is [Rank2D](http://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/features/rankd.html), which is simple and graphs correctly for smaller datasets, but my dataset happens to contain lots of variables, and I would like to at least try to look at it.

Because `yellowbrick` is based on `matplotlib`, I tried many different options to get a large enough image so that the text labels end up fitting next to each other. Setting `dpi=>300` makes the cells in the middle very clear after zooming in, with the same error, so I am thinking this is specifically a text sizing/resolution issue. Changing the image format to `svg`, or anything else, also fails.

Does anybody have any recommendations on what I can do?

Comment: If all the elephants don't fit in the zoo, you can (1) get a larger zoo, (2) exchange them for mice. (1) means change the figure size (2) means change the font size.

Comment: I ended up exploring increasing the two variables height and width with `fig.set_size_inches()`, and saw no initial change. But on larger values, around 30 in. where the kernel took ~3 min. to process the image, the text finally started fitting. Thanks for pointing me toward that implicitly.

Comment: You cracked me up earnest :)